# Can I determine the source of API generated tweets in my twitter account?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have an odd problem with my twitter account. Basically I'm generating tweets automatically via a plugin with my WordPress website.   That works but the tweets appear twice.  I believe this isn't that the plugin is posting twice but want to be sure and just wondered if theres a way I can see technical details about the origin of a tweet?

Comment: The answer is, apparently, irrelevant. Did you find the solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I did not.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON for each tweet there is a source field that shows the utility used to post the tweet.  Example from the REST API documentation:

```
"source":"\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/us\/app\/twitter\/id409789998?mt=12\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003ETwitter for Mac\u003C\/a\u003E"
```

Also, check the timestamps for each tweet to see how far apart they're being posted.  Twitter checks each tweet against the last status posted, and duplication attempts are supposed to be blocked with a 403 error at the `statuses/update.json` endpoint.  Are your duplicated statuses exactly the same?  I'd start to check for the problem by comparing each tweet's JSON and seeing if there are any differences.